# The Number of AND Gates in a Programmable Logic Array

Tags: computer-science

I was reading about programmable logic arrays in my textbook and it said that "The number of AND gates corresponds to the number of input combinations (rows) in the truth table. For n input logic functions, we need a PLA with 2^n n-input AND gates". That makes sense to me, but whenever I look at a diagram of a PLA and compare it to its truth table, it never has 2^n and gates. Every example I see just takes the number of 1s in the output column and makes that the number of and gates. Am I just reading it wrong? Do input combinations only count columns where the output is equal to 1? Wikipedia says it "has 2^n AND Gates for N input variables".

Comment: One example I saw had 3 AND gates because there were 3 rows containing 1s in the output column. You can't get 3 from 2^n. I am extremely confused.

Comment: This statement is just wrong; in fact, every truth-valued function on n Boolean variables can be implemented with fewer than 2^n such AND gates. You only need (at most) as many as there are rows whose output is 1, but if all 2^n rows output 1 then you don't need any gates at all to produce the constant output 1.